# SFML 2.0 Looping a sprite to display more than once

Tags: c++, sfml, sprite-sheet

I have asked a similar question in the past but I still can't get my head around this. I am doing an invaders game based on SFML 2.0. So far I have one sprite sheet which runs through using my clock. This part works just fine:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int spriteWalkSpeed = 10;
int DownspriteWalkSpeed = 5;
int up=-spriteWalkSpeed, down=DownspriteWalkSpeed, left=-spriteWalkSpeed, right=spriteWalkSpeed;

int xVelocity =0, yVelocity=0;

const int SC_WIDTH=800;
const int  SC_HEIGHT= 600;
const float  REFRESH_RATE =0.01f; //how often we draw the frame in seconds

const double delay=0.1;
const int SPRITEROWS=1; //number of ROWS OF SPRITES
const int SPRITECOLS=2;//number of COLS OF SPRITES

std::string gameOver = "Game Over";

int main()
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::RenderWindow App (sf::VideoMode(SC_WIDTH, SC_HEIGHT, 32), "Space Invaders!",sf::Style::Close );

    // Create a clock for measuring time elapsed
    sf::Clock Clock;

    //background texture
    sf::Texture backGround;
    backGround.loadFromFile("images/background.jpg");

    sf::Sprite back;
    back.setTexture(backGround);

    //load the invaders images
    sf::Texture invaderTexture;
    invaderTexture.loadFromFile("images/invaders.png");
    sf::Sprite invadersSprite(invaderTexture);
    std::vector<sf::Sprite> invaderSprites(10, sf::Sprite(invaderTexture));

    int invadersWidth=invaderTexture.getSize().x;
    int invadersHeight=invaderTexture.getSize().y;

    int spaceWidth=invadersWidth/SPRITECOLS;
    int spaceheight=invadersHeight/SPRITEROWS;
    //Sprites

    sf::IntRect area(0,0,spaceWidth,spaceheight);


    invadersSprite.setTextureRect(area);
    invadersSprite.setPosition(30, NULL);


    App.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
    //Collision detection

    // Start game loop  
    while (App.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event Event;
        while (App.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            // Close window : exit
            if (Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App.close();
        }
        // Create an array of 10 sprites (cannot initialise them with textures here)
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            invaderSprites[i].setPosition(30,0);

        if(Clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds()>REFRESH_RATE)
        {
            //carry out updating tasks
            static float spriteTimer=0.0;  //keep track of sprite time
            spriteTimer+=Clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();

            static int count=0; //keep track of where the sub rect is
            if(spriteTimer>delay)
            {
                invaderSprites[i].setTextureRect(area);
                ++count;
                invaderSprites[i].move(xVelocity, yVelocity);   
                if(count==SPRITECOLS) //WE HAVE MOVED OFF THE RIGHT OF THE IMAGE
                {
                    area.left=0;            //reset texture rect at left

                    count=0;                //reset count
                }
                else
                {
                    area.left+=spaceWidth; //move texture rect right
                }


                spriteTimer=0; //we have made one move in the sprite tile - start timing for the next move
            }
            Clock.restart();
        }
        App.draw(back);
            App.draw(invaderSprites[i]);

        // Finally, display the rendered frame on screen
        App.display();
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The issue I am having is that the sprite only shows once, not 10 times (as the for loop states)

```
std::vector<sf::Sprite> invaderSprites(10, sf::Sprite(invaderTexture));

    // Loop over the elements of the vector of sprites
    for (int i = 0; i < invaderSprites.size(); i++) 
    {
        invaderSprites[i].setPosition(30, NULL);
    }
    // Create an array of 10 sprites (cannot initialise them with textures here)
    sf::Sprite invaderSprites[10]; // Loop over each sprite, setting their textures
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        invaderSprites[i].setTexture(invaderTexture);
    }
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the app drawing `invadersSprite` whereas the loop is setup for `invaderSprites`. Even just a little insight into what is going wrong would be such a big help.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. As one small and obvious example, the sound and music is irrelevant to this question, and any references to it can be left out (also the tank and the laser textures and sprites, among others). By doing this, it will make it easier for others to isolate the problems with your code.  Make sure that your reduced example still compiles, unless of course the inability to compile is your problem, which is not the case here.

Comment: I will edit the code now, thanks:
Edited, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am pretty sure it has something to do with the app drawing
>   invadersSprite whereas the loop is setup for invaderSprites.

Yes, that certainly has something to do with it.  You need to call `App.draw(...)` for each sprite that you want to draw.  You're not calling it for any of the sprites in your vector.  For that, you would want a loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<invaderSprites.size(); ++i)
    App.draw(invaderSprites[i]);
```

There are other problems though.  For example, why are you declaring an array of sprites called `invaderSprites`, when you already have a vector of sprites with that same name?  The latter hides the former once it is declared.

Another thing is that you are setting all the sprites to the same position, so even if if you do manage to draw them all, they will all be in the same spot, and as such they will not appear as separate objects.

Comment: There is some left over code from attempts to get it to work. I have tried the App.draw(invaderSprites[i]); in the past but with not much help. Now that I know what the issue is I shall see if I can get it working. Thanks

EDIT:
I also thought that the sprites may be hiding behind one another. I'm not too sure how I would fix this?

Comment: @JohnathanBrown: You fix it by giving them each different positions.  Right now, you are setting each of their positions with `invaderSprites[i].setPosition(30, NULL);` -- So they are all at position x=30, y=0.  (by the way, don't use NULL when you mean 0)

Comment: Right now I am trying this: <code>  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  {
   invaderSprites[i].setPosition(i+5, 0);
   App.draw(invaderSprites[i]);
  }</code> I thought this would of worked

Comment: @JohnathanBrown: Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: It isn't even drawing the looped sprites

Comment: Okay, I modified the code a little. It is displaying the sprite but very weirdly. See updated post

Comment: Sorry for all the comments. <code>    invaderSprites[i].setTextureRect(area);</code> is giving some issue with the way the sprite loads in